# Rails 4 Different background image for home and items index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-image

I should like to set two different background images for the home page of my app and the index view for the items.
I tried this directly in the home view:

```
<div class="container" style="background: url('/assets/images/hom.jpg')">
```

but it doesn't display any image. Someone can help me please?
I already have tried to follow this post but it still doesn't work.
[How to set a different background image for each page in Rails 3 site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144454/how-to-set-a-different-background-image-for-each-page-in-rails-3-site)

Comment: Is it possible that "hom.jpg" is not the correct name of the asset?

Answer (score 0):

Try it without /assets/ in the URL. The rails assets pipeline does not require you to state that it is in an /assets/ directory

Answer (score 0):

You could achive this by setting the appropiate CSS class and setting the image background in you stylesheets. Something like:

```
 <div class="container home">
```

And in a SCSS file:

```
.container.home{
    background-image: image-url("hom.jpg");
}
```

Keep in mind that `image-url` is a helper that should be used in `.scss` files.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by adding the controller and action names to the `body` tag in your layout. Then you can rely on pure CSS to serve different images. In your layout file you can do this:

```
<%= content_tag :body, class: "#{controller_name}-#{action_name}" do %>
  <!-- Your layout content, or everything that should be in the body tag goes here -->
<% end %>
```

This would give you the following HTML:

```
<body class="items-index> <!-- or whatever the current controller/action are -->
```

Then, you can add the relevant CSS.

```
.items-index {
    background-image: image-url("items_index.jpg");
}
.pages-home {
    background-image: image-url("pages_home.jpg");
}
```

You can wrap this in a helper to make it cleaner.

```
def class_for_body
  "#{controller_name}-#{action_name}"
end
```

Or even:

```
def body_tag(&block)
  content_tag :body, yield, class: "#{controller_name}-#{action_name}"
end
```

See [`controller_name`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal/controller_name/class) and [`action_name`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal/controller_name/class) methods provided by Rails.

Comment: I tried adding the <%= content_tag :body, class: "#{controller_name}-#{action_name}" %>  in my /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, and I specified my background-image in the CSS, but all I get is a {:class=>"welcome-index"}  in the top left of my page, I can't understand where I'm failing

Comment: That's because the erb tag is missing `do`. I updated my answer. `content_tag` needs content, and it takes a block. You are passing `class: "#{controller_name}-#{action_name}" ` as that content, so you get that malformed tag. I'll update my answer. Notice the `do` and `<% end %>`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my pages:

```
<div style="background-image: url('/assets/hom.jpg')">
```

And it seems to work locally, but after a push on Heroku the images aren't displayed online.
In addition, the image appears cut, because is referred to a DIV, and I want it referred to the body of my pages.